# Module augmentation for Promise

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I wish to have a generic type over a generic type, aka a higher-kinded-type:

```
abstract class MyClass<URI> { // URI can be Observable or Promise
  // This obviously doesn't work, but that's the idea I have
  abstract run(): URI<number> {
    //... should return Promise<Number> or Observable<Number>, depending on URI
  }
}
```

So I'm trying the method described [here](https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/blob/master/src/HKT.ts) and [here](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/introduction/core-concepts.html#higher-kinded-types), which is basically:

```
export interface HKT<URI, A> {
  readonly _URI: URI;
  readonly _A: A;
}

abstract class MyClass<URI> {
  abstract run(): HKT<URI, number>;
}
```

And I basically just need to do module augmentation on Observable and Promise like this:

```
declare module "rxjs" {
  interface Observable<T> {
    _URI: "Observable";
    _A: T;
  }
}
```

However, how can I do module augmentation for Promise?

```
// This doesn't work...
interface Promise<T> {
  _URI: "Promise";
  _A: T;
}
```

Here's a codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/billowing-darkness-89mry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.

```
declare global {
  interface Promise<T> {
    _URI: 'Promise';
    _A: T;
  }
}
```